# Converting a Circle To a Ring using Canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm using a Custom View where I created a Circle:

```
canvas.drawCircle(width/2, width/2, radius, paint1);
```

Now, I want to empty the circle from inside, something like [a ring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgFW9.png).

Drawing another smaller white circle will raise another problem. I'm planning to make my view listen to user clicks. I want to listen to the clicks on the ring *only!*

Is there a way to exclude some part of the canvas?

Comment: Haven't tested, but try drawing a smaller circle with transparency on paint.

Comment: If you mean setting the paint color to transparent `paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`. Yes I tried. It draw nothing!

Comment: Yeah that was my point, but it doesn't seem to work then ;P

Comment: try: paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));

Comment: It draw a black clickable circle!

Comment: If I found something I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the problem by drawing an inner white circle and filtering the clicks based on the two radius lengths I had.

So, you can't draw an empty circle but you can make a circle to behave like an empty one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

In order to draw a ring (i.e., a circle that is NOT filled in but just has a border, with the area inside transparent) do this:

```
Paint myPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
int strokeWidth=4;  // or whatever
myPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
myPaint.setColor(0xffff0000);   //color.RED
float radius=(float) (0.5*(w+h)*0.5);
canvas.drawCircle((float)0.5*w, (float)0.5*h, radius, myPaint);
```

The call to drawCircle can also be replaced by drawArc like the code below. Either approach will work. The secret sauce is to set the paint style to Paint.Style.STROKE.

```
RectF oval = new RectF(w/2 - radius, w/2 - radius, w/2 + radius, w/2 + radius);
canvas.drawArc(oval, 0, 360, false, myPaint);
```

Answer (score 0):

To draw a ring, use drawArc :

```
RectF oval = new RectF(width/2 - radius, width/2 - radius, width/2 + radius, width/2 + radius);
canvas.drawArc(oval, 0, 360, false, paint1);
```

Comment: It draws a CIRCLE dude! You are basically drawing [an arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_%28geometry%29) with 360 degree.

Comment: I just tried it. It draws a circle! Did you do something special in paint1? Like setting the style to STROKE?

Comment: What would work then? Using Paint.STROKE will not solve my problem. As I stated earlier, I'm planning to listen to user clicks. Your whole ring will be clickable.

Comment: for user click, you cannot add a listener on a drawn part of your canvas. you need to listen to all clicks a filter with bounds yourself.

Comment: that will draw a ring, which is what you seemed to ask.

Comment: @Marc you mean a disk?

Answer (score 0):

this solution works:

```
Paint paintPath;

int circleRadius = (int)
    TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, context.getResources()
    .getDisplayMetrics());

paintPath = new Paint();
paintPath.setStrokeWidth(circleRadius);
paintPath.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paintPath.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
paintPath.setAntiAlias(true);
paintPath.setPathEffect(null);
paintPath.setRasterizer(null);
```

inside on draw

```
RectF rectF = new RectF(centerx - radius, centery - radius,
    centerx + radius, centery + radius);

Path myPath = new Path();
for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i += 1)
{
    myPath.addArc(rectF, i, 1);
}
canvas.drawPath(myPath, paintPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

More short way:

```
draw = function() {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
    ctx.beginPath();
    // ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    // ctx.fill();
ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow";
ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```